# javascript : Regular expression for a:b

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for the occurrence of the pattern `a:b`. This could be of the form

- `a: b` or
- `a :b` or
- `a : b`

(note the optional spaces).

I am new to RegExes and was trying something of the form : `a\s:\sb` but kinda din work..

Can somebody point me out the right one ?

Thanks..

Comment: Do you want to allow a<SPACE><SPACE>:b to match, or is one space the maximum on each side of the colon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `a\s*:\s*b`. Also, this is handy to test: http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm

Comment: I don't think OP wants unlimited number of spaces.

Comment: I as trying your code below and get a false. What m I doing wrong ? var patt1=new RegExp("a\s*:\s*b"); 
document.write(patt1.test("a : b"));

Comment: You forgot to escape the slash with another slash (\\), so the correct version is: `var patt1=new RegExp("a\\s*:\\s*b"); document.write(patt1.test("a : b"));` . But you can also just do `document.write(/a\s*:\s*b/.test("a : b"))` because in Javascript, text between forward slashes (/) creates a RegExp.

Answer (score 4):

Your current regex is 'a\s:\sb'.  Since you didn't make the '\s' part of the pattern optional, this only matches 'a[SPACE]:[SPACE]b', where I am using [SPACE] as a standin for space, tab, or any other whitespace character.  Instead, you can use 'a\s?:\s?b', which makes the whitespace optional.

For more regular expression information, I would recommend [the Perl regular expression tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Comment: I as trying your code below and get a false. What m I doing wrong ?

var patt1=new RegExp("a\s*:\s*b");

document.write(patt1.test("a :   b"));

Comment: In your code, you need to escape the backslash, so you can write `var patt1 = new Regexp("a\\s?:\\s?b");`